# VB.NET Slow Insert of Datagrid rows to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a routine imports a CSV into the datagrid then simply a for-next loop to insert each row, but its running slow 18 Minutes to insert 7100 lines.

Now I have already taken the connection call out of the loop so it only does it once, performs the insertions then closes when finished.

I have seen mentioned to bulk insert 100 rows at a time might help, but that would probably require some conveluted routine to calculate the rows its currently upto and then the odd number after so many lots of 100.

Is there a simple way of just saying insert the whole datagrid instead of 100 rows without a for/next loop?

As you will see below, for fowmatting and ease to read I have broken up my query string, would joining it together into one line make a vast difference? I may have already tried this by the time you reply:

```
        con = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & vardbpath & ";Database=" & vardbname & ";User ID=" & txtUsername.Text & ";Password=" & txtPassword.Text & ";")
        con.Open()

        For i = 0 To rows - 1
            Query = "INSERT into GENERAL (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,ad)"
            Query &= "values ('"
            Query &= (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(18).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(19).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(20).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(22).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(23).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(24).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(25).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(26).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(27).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(28).Value)
            Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(29).Value)
            Query &= "')"

            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

            Try
                Dim j As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If (j > 0) Then txt_folderactivity.Text &= "Row Successfully Inserted" & vbCrLf
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                txt_folderactivity.Text &= "Error Executing SQL command: " & myerror.Message & vbCrLf

            End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the entire csv into the datagrid, you can load only a screen full (or a little more) at a time, then reload on a page with other records on a page up, page down, or search. You may also be able to use a virtual mode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171621.aspx

If you have a giant query to load it all at once, you might want to use a stringBuilder instead of a string. That could prevent another bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're establishing a new connection and creating a new `MySqlCommand` and a new `MySqlConnection` object for each row. This should work slow as entering many data one by one. Try change your code to do bunch of sql commands together like this:

```
    Query = ""
    For i = 0 To rows - 1
        Query = "INSERT into GENERAL (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,ad)"
        Query &= "values ('"
        Query &= (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(18).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(19).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(20).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(22).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(23).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(24).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(25).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(26).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(27).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(28).Value)
        Query &= "','" + (DataGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(29).Value)
        Query &= "');"
    Next

    con = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & vardbpath & ";Database=" & vardbname & ";User ID=" & txtUsername.Text & ";Password=" & txtPassword.Text & ";")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    Try
        Dim j As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (j > 0) Then txt_folderactivity.Text &= "Row Successfully Inserted" & vbCrLf
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        txt_folderactivity.Text &= "Error Executing SQL command: " & myerror.Message & vbCrLf

    End Try
```